How to join table with unrelated table in JPQL for sorting
I have native query that I want to replace with query with JPQL. But it turned out to be not so simple due to the use of a column from an unrelated table message for sorting. For each _chat entry there may be multiple entries from _message or there may not be any entry from _message at all.
All my attempts were failed. Now I am even not sure that it is possible to rewrite with jpql using.
Method with native query:
@Query(
    value = """
        SELECT _chat.*
        FROM _chat
                 LEFT JOIN (SELECT chat_id, max(created_at) as created_at
                            FROM _message
                            GROUP BY chat_id
                ) AS message ON _chat.id = message.chat_id
        WHERE _chat.id in (
            SELECT DISTINCT (chat_id)
            FROM _chat_participant
            WHERE participant_id = ?1
                AND status = 'ACTIVE'
        )
        ORDER BY message.created_at DESC NULLS LAST, _chat.created_at DESC
    """,
    nativeQuery = true
)
fun findAllByUserIdOrderByMessageOrChatCreatedAtDesc(userId: String, pageable: Pageable): Slice<ChatEntity>

Method with jpql. It does not work yet.
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ["participants"])
@Query(
    """
    SELECT DISTINCT c 
    FROM ChatEntity c
    --start of problem part
    LEFT JOIN (                           
        SELECT m FROM MessageEntity m 
        WHERE m.chat.id = c.id 
        ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) 
    -- end of problem part                                   
    LEFT JOIN FETCH c.participants p
    WHERE c.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT (pe.chat.id)
        FROM ParticipantEntity pe
        WHERE pe.participantId = :userId and pe.status = 'ACTIVE'
    )
    ORDER BY 
        -- here I have to add max created_at from _message for ordering
        c.createdAt DESC
    """
)
fun findAllByUserIdOrderByMessageOrChatCreatedAtDesc(userId: String): List<ChatEntity>



Have you tried adding, after the subselect, the alias and the join condirion? Something like LEFT JOIN ( SELECT m FROM MessageEntity m ...) AS jm ON jm.chat.id = c.id etc ?

not exactly the same return results, but maybe close enough. Assuming you have Entity relationships between ChatEntity and MessageEntity via a messages collection in ChatEntity:
"Select c, max(m.created_at) as created FROM ChatEntity c left join c.messages m where  GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY created DESC NULLS LAST, c.created_at DESC"
